# How to not print a scaped quote

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments

I need echo a html string;

```
echo <html><body></body></html>;
result < it was unexpected

echo "<html><body></body></html>";
result "<html><body></body></html>";
```

I do not want the double quotation marks to be displayed;

```
echo ^<html^>^</html^>
result <html></html>
```

It works perfect for me, however the string is large, and if I give scape on all the characters, it will exceed the limit size of the prompt;

**Note, I can not save this string to a file.**

Comment: do you mean escape?

Comment: You may use `set /P "=<html><body></body></html>;" < nul` followed by `echo/`

Comment: Thanks @Aacini, your method worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SET command with quotation mark:

```
SET "string=<html><body></body></html>;"
```

then ECHO it goes ok

Comment: This might work if you escape any quotation marks that may be in the html text.